# CoreStorage functionality (Mac OS X FileVault Encryption)

Tags: storage, driver, kernel-extension

Currently i am working on mac os x.and i want to write a driver which will encrypt a device.
As mac os x 10.7 and above encrypts a device. Similar functionality i want to achieve.
1. Is anyone know how mac os x10.7 does encryption?
2. When it uses the coreStorage functionality, exactly where the password is kept in CoreStorage volume? (Which sector of device)
3. Is there any open source site which can help me debugging the driver.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Filevault 2 is implemented in CoreStorage.kext. That implements a IOStorage filter service which does logical block mapping and optionally encrypts/decrypts blocks using AES-XTS.
2. The password isn't stored with the volume, that's kind of the point. For system volumes, the password you enter on login is used to derive a key with which the master key of the volume can be decrypted. For other volumes, you can choose to store the password in your local OS X keychain.
3. Libfvde is an open-source library for accessing FileVault/CoreStorage volumes. See https://github.com/libyal/libfvde

The [wikipedia article on FileVault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault) is actually pretty detailed and worth reading.

Comment: But, in case of external device encryption password must be stored on that device. So are you having any idea where password is stored on external device?

Comment: No, the password isn't stored on the device, it's stored in your keychain. Look in Keychain Access.app

Comment: If password is stored in system keychain then how device encrypted on one OS can be mounted on other OS?

Comment: You have to type it in on the other machine. Note that the password is used in a key-derivation function, and the derived key is then used to decrypt the volume key. I suggest reading up on some basic cryptography.